# FullCalendar - external events dynamic load in div via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm kinda new to this.

I'm trying to make external events load from a database via ajax. But i'm having problems with the draggable attribute from the fc-events class.

**This is the html for the external events**

```
 <div id='external-events'>
        <p></p>
        <h4>Sesiones</h4>
        <div class="fc-event" id="sesiones"></div>
    </div>
```

**Ajax for the call**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost/eye/admin/ajax/mostrar_sesiones.php',
            success: function(data){
            $('#sesiones').html(data);
        }            
    });
```

**Initialize external events**

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
```

**And the call from DB**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('../../scripts/conexion.php');
$query = "SELECT Sesiones_ID, Sesion_nombre FROM sesiones";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Sesiones_ID, $Sesion_nombre);
    $select="";
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $select.="<div value=". $Sesiones_ID .">".$Sesion_nombre."</div>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

[image]

That image shows how the external events looks like with that code.

It does indeed drag and drop. But the problem is I need the "Sesiones#" to be separated. If I go and add the class at the div in the DB file, then the `Sesiones#` appears separated but don't maintain the draggable attribute. (checked in browser debugger and the div created for each id does have the class).

[image]

Comment: Why don't you add `margins` to the div that you want to seperate?

Answer (score 0):

Putting `class="fc-event"` on the `sesiones` div makes no sense. It's the individual event divs which should be draggable, not the outer div. If you put that class on the outer div and not on the inner one, you end up with no separation between the events as you noted, but more importantly it just won't work - you end up with one big draggable block consisting of *all* your events as one. Clearly that isn't what you want. Demo of the problem: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKwQEJm

However if you remove "fc-event" from the outer div and place it on the inner ones as intended, then each one is created as an individual draggable event. This

```
<div id='external-events'>
  <p></p>
  <h4>Sesiones</h4>
  <div id="sesiones">
    <div class="fc-event" value="1">One</div>
    <div class="fc-event" value="2">Two</div>
    <div class="fc-event" value="3">Three</div>
    <div class="fc-event" value="4">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is the HTML structure you should be aiming to create.

And some CSS like this will add the spacing between the draggable divs, and also cause the cursor to change appropriately when the mouse is over them:

```
#external-events .fc-event {
  margin: 1em 0;
  cursor: move;
}
```

Working demo (based on the [official fullCalendar demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/external-dragging-demo)): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWYQxPE

This is pretty much the same as the HTML you showed in your last screenshot, so it's unclear why it wasn't working for you, unless something else was wrong/missing elsewhere in your code.